# App runs on Simulator, not on device

Tags: ios, date, device

I have this code that I have been re-using for years now. This year it broke, and I don't understand why. In my app, I use a calendar, that is using the [KLDate](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/43508773/) class.

In that class, there is a method that looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSUInteger)month day:(NSUInteger)day {
    NSParameterAssert(1 <= month && month <= 12);
    NSParameterAssert(1 <= day   && day   <= 31);

    if (![super init])
        return nil;

    _year = year;
    _month = month;
    _day = day;

    return self;
}
```

If I run my app in the simulator, it works just fine. However, when I try and run it on my device, the app crashes, telling me

> *** Assertion failure in -[KLDate initWithYear:month:day:], /.../Classes/Calendar/KLDate.m:79

and

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: 1 <= month && month <= 12'

I'm really puzzled. especially, because at some point the code actually WAS running on the device, possibly with a different provisioning profile.

---

OK, I searched a little deeper in the code, and found the place where things go wrong. At a specific moment, initWithYear is called with the wrong parameters:

```
- (id)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSParameterAssert(date!=nil);
    NSInteger year, month, day;
    CFAbsoluteTime absoluteTime = CFDateGetAbsoluteTime((CFDateRef)date);
    CFCalendarRef calendar = CFCalendarCopyCurrent();
    CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime(calendar, absoluteTime, "yMd", &year, &month, &day);
    CFRelease(calendar);

    return [self initWithYear:year month:month day:day];
}
```

When running on the Simulator, the value for **year** is **2015**, as expected. Running the code on the device, the value is **4294969311**. So, somehow, the "CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime" doesn't like my device.

I hope you can help me; let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the initialiser? It is possibly an issue with 64 bit code

Comment: See my latest edits. I'm getting closer

Comment: By the way, your assert statements are not right. I think you intended `NSParameterAssert(1 >= month && month <= 12);` and `NSParameterAssert(1 >= day && day <= 31);`. Also, making year signed, but month and day unsigned, seems a little curious.

Comment: It makes sense because we have years before year 0, but we don't have negative months or days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are getting some 64-bit warnings with this code.

```
NSInteger year, month, day;
…
CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime(calendar, absoluteTime, "yMd", &year, &month, &day);
```

The documentation for [`CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFCalendarRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime) says, "The type of all units is int."

In 64-bit code, `NSInteger` is not the same as `int`.

If you can, look for an updated version `KLDate`, or update your copy to fix the defect.

```
- (id)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSParameterAssert(date!=nil);
    // NSInteger year, month, day;
    int year, month, day;
    CFAbsoluteTime absoluteTime = CFDateGetAbsoluteTime((CFDateRef)date);
    CFCalendarRef calendar = CFCalendarCopyCurrent();
    CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime(calendar, absoluteTime, "yMd", &year, &month, &day);
    CFRelease(calendar);

    return [self initWithYear:year month:month day:day];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even know where to start thinking. Does this mean that the Simulator doesn't run in 64 bit mode?

Comment: @Sjakelien Yes, the simulator can run in 64-bit mode. It all depends on the project settings, which is a very different question.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, while I'm glad you solved your problem, in addition to `CFCalendarDecomposeAbsoluteTime`, you might also consider `NSCalendar` method `components:fromDate:`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSParameterAssert(date);

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

    return [self initWithYear:components.year month:components.month day:components.day];
}
```